# What is the proper way to RTSP stream, transcode and save to file?

Tags: vlc, libvlc

While showing the rstp-stream, we are trying to transcode, and record it to file for later use.

**VLC 2.1.1** seems to work when using

```
vlc rtsp-stream :sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp1v,vb=700,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=asf,dst="C:\file.mpg"}}"
```

This seems to be broken on **VLC 2.2.4**

Documentation on VLC's wiki seems outdated.

Comment: Why are you muxing `asf` into an `mpg` file?

Comment: @aergistal was coded like that (legacy code).... More study of Decoders/Mux/Containers and the VLC Convert Settings helped find a good setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrepancies with the `vcodec/mux` pairing as well as using `samplerate` instead of `vb` seem to fix it.

```
vlc rtsp-stream :sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,scale=0.5,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='C:\file.mpg'}}"
```